# Magento 2, get field backend model by path

Tags: magento2, backend, plugin

I'm making a plugin for the `Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface file.`

I need to get the config value from database.

Right now, I manage to accomplish this, but I'm having an issue with obscured fields.

I'm getting the value that comes directly from database.

If I inject the `EncryptorInterface` I can `decrypt` it, but the problem is that I need to know when is necessary to `decrypt` and when should I need to return the value from database.

I have at this point of the flow the path for the config option **(example: carriers/usps/userid )**

I was looking for a way to detect the backend model for the field using the path to load the model.

I tried something like this:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$field = $objectManager->create('Magento\Config\Model\Config\Structure')->getElement($path);
```

And then try this to get the backend Model:

```
    if ($field->hasBackendModel()) {
        $backendModel = $field->getBackendModel();
        //backend model is empty
    }
```

Not sure how I can achieve to detect if the field has backend model Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Encrypted

Is there some way to read the xml tree, and using the field path get the backend model, so I can know if I should use decrypt for returning the value or not?

Answer (score 1):

`Magento\Framework\App\Config\Initial->getMetaData()` returns an array of all config paths with a backend model that requires processing (decrypting) before being written to cache.

Specifically, the below code will give you a clean array to reference a given config path against to see if it needs decrypting.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$metaData = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\App\Config\Initial')->getMetaData();

$pathsRequiringDecryption = [];

foreach ($metaData as $path => $processor) {
    if ($processor['backendModel'] == 'Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Encrypted') {
        $pathsRequiringDecryption[] = $path;
    }
}
```

Obviously use proper DI rather than the object manager in production yada yada you know the deal.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add **backend_model** in config.xml for those filed which type obscure.

Ex:

```
<field id="account" translate="label comment" type="obscure" sortOrder="40" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
    <label>Account ID</label>
    <backend_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Encrypted</backend_model>
</field>
```

You need to add in confix.xml like:

```
<account backend_model="Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Encrypted">TEST</account>
```

[For more detail check dhl module](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/app/code/Magento/Dhl/etc/config.xml#L28)

Now when you use the following code, Magento will return actual value not encrypted value:

```
$this->scopeConfig->getValue('yoursection/yourgroup/yourfield')
```

Comment: Hi Sohel! I know how to use an encrypted field, but what I need to solve is to get an already existing field, using the path, and see somehow if it should be decrypted or not